# ipython and reference counts

Tags: python, memory-leaks, ipython, reference-counting

It would appear that `ipython` may be retaining references to objects when I'm not expecting it to.

Consider the following script (`grc.py`):

```
import sys
obj = []
print sys.getrefcount(obj)
```

When I run it in `ipython`:

```
Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)| (r271:86832, Nov 29 2010, 13:51:37)

In [1]: %run grc.py
2

In [2]: print sys.getrefcount(obj)
4
```

What's going on? Where did the extra two references come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, IPython does maintain references to objects behind the scenes. Using %run in particular leaves references in the machinery that handles modules.

We're working on it in the development version (which will hopefully become 0.11 soon) - see [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/141) for more information. The references will still be there, but there'll be ways to get rid of them (`%reset` to clear them all, or `%xdel obj` for a single one).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for this. In the ideal world, it would be great if there was a way to nuke just the references used internally by `ipython` (or to prevent it from creating them in the first place). The reason I care about this so much is that the objects in my real-life use case are multi-gigabyte `numpy` arrays and I'd like the memory management to behave exactly the same regardless of whether I run the script using `python` or `ipython`.

Comment: @aix: It would be easy enough to tweak `xdel` so it leaves the references in the user namespace. But I don't think it could be done from within the script, as the references are made after the script finishes. It could be that there's a better way to do the %run code, that doesn't create references. If you know about such things, we're happy to point you at the relevant bits of code.